# Error with mscoree.dll when executing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

For a few days now, whenever I try to start Visual Studio 2017 I get an error that says that an specified procedure couldnt be found

[image: Error message]

I have tried the .NET Framework repair form Microsoft and it couldn't find the problem, I have also tried uninstalling and installing Visual Studio 2017 but the installation also throws the error (though it finishes and I can try to open Visual Studio again).

I have tried the .NET Framework installers but they say the framework is already installed so it won't do anything, and I can't find any way to uninstall .NET Framework in Windows 10.

I searched through Google for some versions of the DLL and putting it in the *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319* folder but none have changed anything.

Comment: Start visual studio in safe mode, see if you get the same results, if you dont, its most likely an extension or plugin. however i think there is something deeper going on, especially if you cant uninstall.

Comment: @MichaelRandall It managed to open, but when I try to open my project it throws an error with an stack trace, this is the first part of the trace becaus its too big for a comment

The "ResolveComReference" task failed unexpectedly.
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at Microsoft.Win32.NativeMethods.NtQuerySystemInformation(Int32 query, IntPtr dataPtr, Int32 size, Int32& returnedSize)

Comment: "*I searched through Google for some versions of the DLL and putting it in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 folder*" Remove those, first of all. That's not how to solve this kind of problems, but you can easily make them worse.

Comment: @dxiv I deleted them already, it was a quick test to see if it helped

Comment: @Coirotomas If all else fails, and given the reference to `ResolveComReference`, you could run a capture with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and try to figure out which step fails where. That's rather tedious, though.